# How do i add remote mercurial repositories in Jira

Tags: mercurial, jira

I am using jira 4.4.3 and mercurial plugin version 4.1.0

When i try to add a repositorty, i get the exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Steps taken:

1. Install Jira and Mercurial plugin.
2. The mercurial plugin was manually installed as jar file along with other plugins in the following location:

   ```
   root@jiraeng:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/plugins/installed-plugins# ls -l
   total 17712
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira  310943 2011-11-07 17:02 jira-hudson-plugin-1.0.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira 2823919 2011-11-07 17:00 jira-javamelody-1.32.1.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira  173892 2011-11-07 17:00 mercurial-jira-plugin-4.1.0.jar
   -rw------- 1 jira jira 1244915 2011-11-07 12:47 plugin.2065440881919807685.jira-fisheye-plugin-  3.2.3.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira 3551278 2011-11-07 18:13 plugin.3295151510657051340.jira-greenhopper-plugin-5.8.2.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira 1258615 2011-11-07 18:13 plugin.4689593656531536722.jira-fisheye-plugin-3.4.7.jar
   -rw------- 1 jira jira 8540534 2011-11-07 12:48 plugin.8779650565160096778.jira-importers-plugin-3.5.2.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 jira jira  216700 2011-11-07 17:00 trafficlight-1.2.2.jar
   ```
3. Jira was restarted
4. Login as Administrator
5. Goto http://jiraeng.company.com:8080/secure/AdminSummary.jspa
6. click on "mercurial repositories" http://jiraeng.company.com:8080/secure/ViewMercurialRepositories.jspa
7. Add a mercurial repo
8. Repository Root is chosen as http://jiraeng.company.com:8080/secure/ViewMercurialRepositories.jspa
9. this repo can be cloned without password from command line
10. Click add

Get the exception:

Comment: Can you be more precise about the error ? And also better explain the step you're taking to produce it. It will also be nice to know what you'we already tried to fix the issue...